# Questions about Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have done some project using Sencha Touch -> www.estof.net/sencha (php + sencha). I want to ask you guys some questions:

a) I want to create app using sencha and upload to iPad. My app will work only if i connected to wifi or whatever internet?

b) For example i did some application, draw icon. Can I put it on iPad? Then click on icon and my application will work? (will be nice if app tried even to connect to Internet, but APP ICON will be on iPad)

c) Or sencha using only as a web-site?

Answer (score 3):

1. Sencha apps can work in offline mode. This is done by using a manifest file to cache the required files. [This will explain more about it](http://www.sencha.com/learn/taking-sencha-touch-apps-offline?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonu6XLZKXonjHpfsX56OslUKC0lMI/0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4DTdQhcOuuEwcWGog80wlWGeiU). [This is another tutorial using phone](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap) gap.
2. Yes you can create app icons for your apps. In this [link](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/getting-started.html#DetCreatingJS), you can see an attribute named 'icon' which specifies the images to be used as the icon. In safari when you take your site, and press the option button on the bottom, there is an option to 'ADD to Home Screen'. This option will add the icon to the home screen.
3. If you go to the sencha forums and check their showcase section you can see many apps that are actually sold in the app store.

The upcoming version of Sencha is said to have their own api's to access native feature of a phone os. Its more detailed on their website.